# Conditional probability. Targeting events

Tags: probability, statistics

> Electric motors coming off two assembly lines are pooled for storage in a common stockroom, and the room contains an equal number of motors from each line. Motors are periodically sampled from that room and tested. It is known that 10% of the motors from line I are defective and 15% of the motors from line II are defective. If a motor is randomly selected from the stock-room and found to be defective, find the probability that it came from line I.

Here is my way to solve it. First it is a conditional probability. The formula is

$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P (A\cap B) }{ P(B) }.$$

$P(B)$ = probability that it came from line 1 = $2 P_1$.

Now here is where it gets interesting. What would be $P(A\cap B)$ in that case? 
Is $P(A \cap B)=P(\text{came from line 1 * defective})$?

Comment: When you are doing a conditional probability calculation, it is useful to write down *explicitly* what you mean by $A$ and $B$. In this case, you want to know the probability the motor came from line I **given** that it is defective. So $A$ is the event "came from line I" and $B$ is the event "is defective."  Now everything should be straightforward. We have $P(A)=1/2$. For $P(B)$, defective happens if came from I and is defective **or** came from II and is defective. Thus P(B)=(1/2)(0.10)+(1/2)(0.15)$.

Comment: pefect :) u made my day

Comment: im confuse in P (AB). how de we get the intersection. (multiply a and b doesnt seem to work)

Comment: ei last question
i cant still figure out to find the intersection between a and b
what i just do is 0.5 * .01
but cant get the logic behind it
im trying to figure out by using venn diagram

Comment: $P(AB)=P(A)P(B|A)$.  $P(A)=1/2$, $P(B|A)=0.10$ (we were told that if from line I, probability defective is $0.10$). Or more concretely, think in terms of tree, $P(AB)$ is probability we picked from line I, times the probability a line I item is defective. Or more concretely still, $1000$ items in stock, $500$ from I, $500$ from I. Then approx. $50$ bad from I, $75$ bad from II. So $P(AB)=50/1000$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(B) is not P(came from line 1) in this problem.  You are being asked to calculate P(came from line 1 | is defective) so B is "is defective" and A is "came from line 1".  You're right that P(AB) is "Came from line 1 and is defective", and if you know how to calculate P(B) correctly in this case then you're essentially doing the same thing as you would if you used [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

To calculate P(B) correctly: P(B) needs to be the probability that any given motor *in the entire factory* is defective, not just from line I.  Use the [Law of Total Probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

For P(AB): This is itself a conditional probability problem.  Consider P(is defective | came from line 1) = P(defective and from line 1)/P(came from line 1)

Comment: Right.  Try this: Imagine the factory has exactly 100 motors in it (giving 50 in each line).  How many of them are defective?

Comment: Can you please stop deleting your comments so I don't look like a madman talking to himself?  lol

Comment: any idea to get P(AB). my thought is finding intersection. but doesnt work

Comment: ok sorry chad. my fault

Comment: I think I made my last edit while you were making your comment (I don't have enough rep to post in the comment thread above).  Tell me if that makes sense

Comment: P(AB)=1/2 * [(1/2)(0.10)+(1/2)(0.15)] ??

Comment: yes it makes sense

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2278/discussion-between-chad-miller-and-user963499)